# Density of a random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y \sim U[0,1]$ be two independent uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ random variables. Let $Z := \max(X,Y)$. I'm interested in the probability density function of the vector $(X,Z)^T$. The CDF of $(X,Z)^T$ is
\begin{align*}
F_{X,Z}(x,z) &= \mathbb{P}(X \leq x, \max(X,Y) \leq z) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x, X \leq z, Y \leq z) = \\
&= xz I\{0 \leq x \leq z \leq 1\} + z^2 I\{0 \leq z \leq 1, z \leq x\} + x I\{0\leq x \leq 1, 1 < z\} + I\{1 \leq x, 1 \leq z\}
\end{align*}

Now $p_{X,Z}(x,z) = \frac{\partial^2 F_{X,Z}(x,z)}{\partial x \partial z} = I\{0 \leq x \leq z \leq 1\}$. But $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}I\{0 \leq x \leq z \leq 1\} dxdz = \frac{1}{2} \neq 1$

The setting of the problem is very simple but I just don't understand where is the mistake.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb P(X\leq x, X\leq z, Y\leq z) = \mathbb P(X\leq\min(x,z))\mathbb P(Y\leq z)$

Comment: A density of $(X,Z)$ does not exist in the usual sense because $X=Z$ occurs with positive probability.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have the random variable $Z:=\max(X,Y)=\begin{cases}X&X>Y\\Y&X\le Y \end{cases}$, so in general
$$F_Z(z):=P(Z\le z)=P(\max (X,Y)\le z)=P[(X\le z, X>Y)\cup(Y\le z,X\le Y)]$$
since $\{X\le Y\}$ and $\{X >Y\}$ are mutually exclusive
$$P[(X\le z, X>Y)\cup(Y\le z,X\le Y)]=P(X\le z,X>Y)+P(Y\le z,X\le Y)\implies\\F_Z(z)=P(X\le z, Y\le z)=F_{XY}(z,z)\text{ but for independence}\\F_Z(z)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)$$
observing that
$$\Big(\{X\le z\}\cap\{X>Y\}\Big)\cup\Big(\{Y\le z\}\cap\{X\le Y\}\Big)=\{X\le z\}\cap\{Y\le z\}.$$
You can find density function by $f_Z(z)=\dfrac{d}{dz}P(Z\le z)$.

Comment: The question isn't about the density of $Z$.